# Android ArrayList size returning 1 even if no item in the list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am working with Android. I have an ArrayList of string data and I saved whole Arraylist as a single string in local database.Later I fetch this string from db and convert this string into array list as,

case 1:

```
  String dbString=[10,5,34,67];  // array list as string
  String replace = dbString.toString().replace("[", "");
            String replace1 = replace.replace("]", "");
            mysignimgList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
```

case 2:

```
  String dbString2=[];  //empty array list as string
  String replace = dbString2.toString().replace("[", "");
            String replace1 = replace.replace("]", "");
            mysignimgList2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
```

but in the second case even if there is no item in the arraylist ,its size will get as mysignimgList2.size()=1.

Comment: Can you show us what `replace1` contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case 2

```
String dbString2="[]";
```

In your code it is trying to split it into pieces with **comma (,)** as **seperator**.
In case if it finds the separator it split it into pieces. But in case if it doesnot finds any separtor it will assign the given as single string in the returned list.

In your case a String array with one element having value **""**, or to say **empty string**.

Replace `String dbString2="[]";` with `String dbString2="[,]";`.

In this case it will return a size of 0 with no elements.

Comment: Won't that give `2` elements??

Answer (score 8):

This is a feature of [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression **or is terminated by the end of the string**.

So splitting an empty string returns a 1-entry array containing one empty string.

Comment: then how can I check whether the array list is empty or not ?

Comment: @UserAndroid - Compare `replace1` with `""`.